# Flyback Transformer Connection & Construction

Tags: transformer, flyback

I don't understand how the coils are wound in a flyback transformer.
Can someone post an image or explain.

Basically I can understand all the calculation needed to design the flyback transformer. However, when it comes to winding structure, it is really confusing.

Based on my view, different transformer maker sometime uses different transformer winding structure. Example such as separate winding & stacked winding. I totally dont understand the reason behind that.

Does anyone know what is the better way to understand the transformer winding connection & construction for below image?

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

This transformer is almost same as [Flyback Transformer Design for the IRIS40xx Series](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1024.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535591115e0f6d)

[image: Figure 3]

You can refer Fig.3

Comment: YOU find an image that confuses you and place it in your question.

Comment: How about this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458356/transformer-construction-diagram?rq=1

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a one-suit-for-all winding structure. This does not exist. Instead you design your transformer to suit your application.

Comment: Hi @Andy aka, based on my example transformer picture, do you know why in the primary section, P1 & P2 are stacked & in secondary, S1 & S2 are separated? What is the actual number of turns for secondary? In my calculation, the number of secondary turns should be 7. But from the image, they are parallel of 7 turns (S1 & S2)

Comment: 7 turns in parallel with 7 turns in the same winding direction, how many total turns did that equal @user218385 ?

Comment: @user218385 That is a design thing and not a winding structure thing. P1 and P2 are connected and that central connection will suit a driver that isn't necessarily a flyback driver. It looks more like a forward converter primary. Whether S1 and S2 are separated or connected has nothing to do with the transformer being flyback or otherwise; it's a design thing i.e. the designer needed a trafo with separated secondaries for whatever reason but not anything to do with it being flyback or forward converter operating principle.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, yes you're correct, that's a transformer connection diagram. I update another picture that shows the winding structure.

Comment: The added picture doesn't alter my answers in the comment above. It still doesn't look like a flyback trafo to me.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, it is actually transformer from flyback smps circuit for audio system application that rated ~50W.

Comment: Please provide a link to it.

Comment: I cant provide a link to it as it is too confidential. Basically this flyback circuit is developed by other company. Therefore, I cant share too much information. But based on spec information they given, basically they developing this transformer for flyback circuit application. I already tested this transformer in my flyback circuit and it works well.

Comment: Hi @winny, 3.5?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, maybe you can refer to this link https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1024.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535591115e0f6d you can refer to Fig.3 which is almost same as my example. In this document, basically the transformer winding is for flyback circuit.

Comment: Figure 3 shows a flyback transformer but the trafo picture in your question doesn't I believe. If you can't link me to the design then what is this question all about? If you have difficulties with understanding the design then ask the designer in the "other company".

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, ok its up to you.

Comment: @user218385 No. Please go back to the law of induction and think of how a transformer works.

Comment: Hi @winny, meaning the secondary current will doubled but the actual turns is remaining the same?

Comment: @user218385 You are making it difficult for yourself. Start with the voltage alone. What does the law of induction tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get transformer action, both the primary winding and the secondary winding must  simply **link** the core.

The shape and relative disposition of those two windings are then arranged to meet other requirements. Flybacks can be used in a range of different circumstances, so you may be confused by seeing different arrangements for different purposes. The final design is always a compromise between several mutually exclusive aims.

If you want tight coupling, so low leakage inductance in the transformer, then you might want to interleave the windings. This reduces the kickback that the primary must handle.

If you want high voltage isolation between the two windings, then you might want to put one at one end, and the other at the other, at the expense of leakage inductance.

If you want the highest frequency of operation, then you would segment the windings, making each of several thin 'pancakes', rather than several layers. This reduces the self capacitance of each winding, thus raising the self resonant frequency (SRF).

Segmenting the high voltage winding is also good for improving the withstanding voltage across the winding. Segmentation of course reduces the percentage of copper filling the winding window, increasing copper losses.

If you do wind in layers, then winding each layer in the same direction, with a quick return between layers, gives better insulation performance and better SRF than winding to and fro on alternate layers.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explaination. Based on your explaination, can we said that different winding structure will mainly affect the leakage inductance value of the transformer itself?

Comment: it does affect leakage inductance, SRF and voltage withstanding. Which of those is most important is up to your application.

Comment: I always enjoy reading your comments regarding this subject. Thanks, again.

Comment: Hi @Neil_UK, thank you. Now I'm more clear on what I'm doing.

Comment: Hi @Neil_UK, based on my example transformer picture, do you know why in the primary section, P1 & P2 are stacked & in secondary, S1 & S2 are separated? What is the actual number of turns for secondary? In my calculation, the number of secondary turns should be 7. But from the image, they are parallel of 7 turns (S1 & S2)

Comment: @user218385 The interleaving of primaries and secondaries suggests that tight coupling is an asset. Are you sure this is a flyback transformer, the centre-tapped P1/2 is unusual in that regard, unless the CT is unused?